# Set up a PostgreSQL database on Heroku (required entityManagerFactory)

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, heroku, spring-data-jpa

I would like to create a web-application on Heroku implemented in Spring Boot. Finally, I managed to deploy a plain project with "Whitelabel error page 404", confirming correctness of deploying.

I followed by (almost the same): https://devcenter-assets0.herokucdn.com/articles/spring-boot-memcache

Unfortunately, I got only one (I hope) problem with Spring Data JPA (after adding a service (for example Spring Security and Lombok work properly) that is making it impossible for me to build app and use PostgreSQL:

```
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in io.github.plkpiotr.fifabackend.controller.TaskController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.plkpiotr</groupId>
    <artifactId>fifa-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>fifa-backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.maxActive=10
spring.datasource.maxIdle=5
spring.datasource.minIdle=2
spring.datasource.initialSize=5
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Task.java:

```
package io.github.plkpiotr.fifabackend.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public Task() {}

    public Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Task[id=%d, name='%s']", this.id, this.name);
    }

}
```

TaskRepository.java:

```
package io.github.plkpiotr.fifabackend.repository;

import io.github.plkpiotr.fifabackend.model.Task;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Long> {}
```

TaskController.java:

```
package io.github.plkpiotr.fifabackend.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.lang.Iterable;

import io.github.plkpiotr.fifabackend.model.Task;
import io.github.plkpiotr.fifabackend.repository.TaskRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepo;

    @Autowired
    public TaskController(TaskRepository repo) {
        this.taskRepo = repo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAllTasks(ModelMap model) {
        Iterable<Task> tasks = this.taskRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("tasks", tasks);
        model.addAttribute("newTask", new Task());
        return "task";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newTask(ModelMap model,
                          @ModelAttribute("newTask") @Valid Task task,
                          BindingResult result) {
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            this.taskRepo.save(task);
        }
        return showAllTasks(model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteTask(ModelMap model, @RequestParam("taskId") Long id) {
        this.taskRepo.deleteById(id);
        return showAllTasks(model);
    }
}
```

I tried:

1). Add differentiated dependencies (h2, hibernate-core, ...)

2). Remove /.m2/ folder and redownload dependencies

3). Don't cry after other failed attemps...

And if you are intrested in **cloning repo**:
https://github.com/plkpiotr/fifa-backend

In addition to this, if I deleted inside of TaskController.java I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
```

How to fix the problems?

Comment: This setting looks suspicious: spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration   Have you tried removing that line? Basically you're telling Spring not to auto-configure your datasource so it makes sense that you wouldn't have an EntityManagerFactory here if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for you reply :) Without the line is error as follows:
`Description:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url

Action:
Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).`

Comment: If I look at a Spring-Boot application that I have successfully deployed to Heroku I see that I have the following line in addition to your properties: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your_database  Note that Heroku replaces this url with one of its own but perhaps the property needs to be present?

Comment: I'll check it now.

Comment: Also you can get rid of all the stuff you have on your FifaBackendApplication class, all you need is @SpringBootApplication on such a simple application. Spring will pick up on that you have entities by itself since you have the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency defined.

Comment: After adding the one line: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.` So, it's better. I will try add username and password. About your the third comment:  the annotations were added due to looking for the solution, not on purpose.

Comment: Try adding these properties: spring.datasource.username=your_user
spring.datasource.password=some_password   These also get replaced by Heroku so they can probably be random

Comment: Unfortunately, I got: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile`

Comment: Did you get rid of all the annotations on your FifaBackendApplication class? Could you push what you currently have to your git repo and I'll take a look at it

Comment: Unbelievable, after deleting the annotations in configuration class, the project was build. I pushed the changes, I only don't see any JSON, after the GET, but it is so much better ; )

Comment: Great! Make sure you add this setting as well: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create  Otherwise your database tables that correspond to your entities won't be created. Of course once you grow more advanced you'll want to start using Liquibase for managing your database (and thus no longer put the ddl-auto setting to create but rather to validate) but to get it working the create option is what you want.

Comment: If you create some data in your database you will probably also see JSON after the GET. You can do that either by manually inserting into the database or by adding the INSERT statements in a file named "data.sql" in your src/main/resources directory. The INSERT statements will be performed when you start up your application and after that your GET should start showing you data.

Comment: [See a screenshot ;)](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/21959354/42664337-82c4590a-863a-11e8-9956-178fd1a8706f.PNG)
I will have to only learn about migration of data, becuase it works local :)

Answer (score 0):

`@EntityScan`, `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@ComponentScan` do not support a wildcard syntax. For example you currently use:

```
@EntityScan("io.github.plkpiotr.*")`
```

but it should be just the base package name

```
@EntityScan("io.github.plkpiotr")
```

Comment: It causes:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile`

But, the annotation was added due to looking for the solution, honestly - not on purpose.

Comment: Add expected version of [Javassit](https://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist) and see if it helps. If so debug why it's missing, your `pom.xml` looks ok.